# How to read a UTF-8 encoded list of string tokens into a vector?

Tags: string, r, input, utf-8, token

I have a UTF-8 encoded text file with one token per line. I would like to read it into a vector. This is on MSWindows, version 3.0.1. I understand that the default encoding is UTF-8, right?

I am looking for a code snippet like the ones on

http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/html/r4.html

from 'R by example'

http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/index.html

However they do not have a UTF-8 example, only ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either read it in with read.table() and then extract the column as a vector,  or with scan().

```
 vect <- scan(file="path/to/file1.txt", what=character(0) )
```

You would not need to use UTF-8 as the encoding,  since you know that it is the default, but there is the option of doing so:

```
vect <- scan(file="path/to/file1.txt", what=character(0), encoding="UTF-8" )
```

The NEWS file for R 3.0.0 said:

" o readLines() and scan() (and hence read.table()) in a UTF-8 locale now discard a UTF-8 byte-order-mark (BOM). Such BOMs are allowed but not recommended by the Unicode Standard: however Microsoft applications can produce them and so they are sometimes found on websites.

The encoding name "UTF-8-BOM" for a connection will ensure that a UTF-8 BOM is discarded. "

So perhaps the need for the encoding argument indicated either that you were in a nonUTF-8 locale and didn't tell us or that you were using an outdated R version?

Comment: This first expressions works fine, however it has a BOM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark in front of the first token. The second one is correct. So we need to indicate the encoding.